# Can I connect my Innolux LCD to my TFP401 HDMI/DVI Decoder 40-Pin TTL Breakout?

Tags: hdmi, display

### Setup

- [Raspberry Pi 2](http://www.raspberrypi.org/raspberry-pi-2-on-sale/)
- [TFP401 HDMI/DVI Decoder to 40-Pin TTL Breakout - Without Touch](https://www.adafruit.com/products/2218)
- [Innolux 5.6 LCM aSi TFT type LCD](http://www.panelook.com/AT056TN53%20V.1_Innolux_5.6_LCM_overview_1525.html)

I am hoping to be able to connect the Pi2 to the Driver using a small HDMI cable and then the FFC from the Innolux to the driver.

If my current Innolux screen isn't compatible, why? and what should I be looking at on the LCD specs to get the TFP401 to work with my Pi2?

Answer (score 2):

Both the Adafruit TFP401 and Innolux AT056TN53 display have a 40-pin TTL interface, but a quick look at the interface pinouts is a fast way to determine that they are not immediately compatible.

For example, take a look at the pinout configuration in the datasheets for the following Adafruit (On Tat) displays that are listed as compatible with the TFP401. You'll see that the listings are fairly identical (save for differences in acronyms and terminology).

- https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/KD50G21-40NT-A1.pdf (Section 5.7)
- https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/product-files/2354/adafruit_SPEC-YX700WV03_REV.A-787880.pdf (Section 4)
- https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/product-files/1591/SPEC-CH430WQ01-T_Rev.A.pdf (Section 4)

Conversely, in section 2 (on page 5) of the Innolux data sheet, you'll see that the pinouts are very different.

- http://www.bdtic.com/datasheet/Innolux/AT056TN53-V1.pdf

The TFP401 page also states that it's designed specifically for their displays, so it may not even be possible to reconfigure it to drive a display with a different pinout configuration.